# How to use logger in DAG callbacks with Airflow running on Google Composer?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow

We are running Apache Airflow in a Google Cloud Composer environment. This runs a pre-built Airflow on Kubernetes, our image version is `composer-2.0.32-airflow-2.3.4`.

In `my_dag.py`, we can use the `logging` module to log something, and the output is visible under "Logs" in Cloud Composer.

```py
import logging

log = logging.getLogger("airflow")
log.setLevel(logging.INFO)

log.info("Hello Airflow logging!")
```

However, when using the same logger in a callback (e.g. `on_failure_callback` of a DAG), the log lines do not appear anywyhere - not in the Airflow workers, nor the airflow-scheduler nor dag-processor-manager. I am triggering a DAG failure by setting a short (e.g. 5 minute) timeout, and I confirmed that the callback is indeed running by making an HTTP request to a webhook inside the callback. The webhook is called but the logs are nowhere to be found.

Is there a way to log something in a callback, and find the logs somewhere in Airflow?

Comment: Have you checked the logs from `Cloud Logging` ?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately in the `on_failure_callback` method, the logs doesn't appears in the DAG tasks logs (Webserver), but normally the logs are written in `Cloud Logging`.

In `Cloud Logging`, select the `Cloud Composer Environment` resource, then the location (`europe-west1`) and, finally, the name of the composer environment: `composer-log-error-example`.

[image]

Then select the `airflow-worker` :

[image]

You can check this [link](https://medium.com/syntio/write-error-logs-from-composer-and-create-an-alert-policy-on-stackdriver-c9c2f5e88dc8)

Also for the log in Airflow DAGs and method called by `on_failure_callback`, I usually directly use the `Python` `logging` without other init and it works well :

```py
import logging

def task_failure_alert(context):
  logging.info("Hello Airflow logging!")
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and effort putting this together! When I go to the logs, my query looks like this: `resource.type="cloud_composer_environment" resource.labels.environment_name="airflow" resource.labels.location="europe-west3"`. In those logs, I can find my own log lines from the DAG setup, but all the log statements from inside the callbacks are still missing. I tried using simply `logging.info` but for me it seems to make no difference

Comment: You're welcome, it's the same for `logging.error` ?

Comment: Just tried it, I can confirm it's the same for `logging.error`

Comment: In your logged messages, can you add a kind of characters `###############my log`, in order to search them more easily in Cloud Logging ? You also have to be sure you searched your logs in the correct dates range

Comment: For the filter, you can also try with : `resource.labels.environment_name="airflow-worker" `

Comment: Since it seems like a bug in Airflow/Composer, I created an issue with minimal example on the Airflow GitHub tracker: https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/29442#issuecomment-1425031828

Comment: Ok I will take a look. It works on my side with a recent version of Composer and Airflow 2.

Comment: Having the same issue. Task-level callbacks are fine, but DAG-level callbacks aren't visible in Cloud Logging

Comment: You have errors outside of tasks ?